# interp1d for pandas time series

Tags: pandas, scipy

I want to interpolate between times in a pandas time series. I would like to use scipy.interpolate.interp1d (or similar). The `pandas.interpolate` function is undesirable, as it would require inserting `nan` values and then replace them using interpolation (and thus modifying the dataset). What I tried to do:

```
from datetime import datetime
import scipy.interpolate as si
import pandas as pd
d1 = datetime(2019, 1, 1)
d2 = datetime(2019, 1, 5)
d3 = datetime(2019, 1, 10)
df = pd.DataFrame([1, 4, 2], index=[d1, d2, d3], columns=['conc'])
import scipy.interpolate as si
f = si.interp1d(df.index, df.conc)
f(datetime(2019, 1, 3))
```

All is good until the last line, where I get an `ValueError: object arrays are not supported`. Strangely enough `f.x` nicely shows the dates as `dtype='datetime64[ns]`, so I was hoping it would work. Anybody know how to get this to work?

Comment: You need to convert the interpolation point `datetime(2019, 1, 3)` to `datetime64[ns]`

Comment: The error is confusing but not actually misleading

Comment: `f(np.datetime64(datetime(2019, 1, 3)))` gives me `TypeError: invalid type promotion`

Comment: Odd. `np.datetime64(datetime(2019, 1, 3))` and `np.datetime64(datetime(2019, 1, 3), 'ns')` are not a problem. Lemme check

Comment: `f(pd.to_datetime('2019-1-3'))` gives `ValueError: object arrays are not supported` again. Am I trying something to do something that is not implemented? Or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: It might be that interp1d doesn't support datetime. Try `np.interp1d`

Comment: `np.interp(np.datetime64(datetime(2019, 1, 3)), df.index, df.conc)` gives as value `1`, but that is wrong. It doesn't throw an error message. The docs of `np.interp` say that values must be floats, which I am violating.

Comment: Ahh. That would explain it. I'm sure the scipy object is based on the numpy function

Comment: Let me play around a bit and show you my usual workaround

Comment: Just saw your issue https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/14941. Beat me , I only just got to a desktopto it :)

Answer (score 4):

This works, but is arguably a bit ugly:

```
f = si.interp1d(pd.to_numeric(df.index), df.conc)
f(pd.to_numeric(pd.to_datetime(['2019-1-3'])))
```