# Interpolation of big data sets (interp1d) with Timestamps - Python

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, bigdata, interpolation

I'm dealing with two big data sets. Both represent different data from 1990 until 2020.
One of them has a time step of 10 minutes and the other of 1h.

This means that while for one I have ±1 400 000 data points, for the other I have only ±200 000.

The first issue is that the time column of both .csv files is different. This means that one of them is a pandas Timestamp whilst the other is just a string

In order to use data from both Data sets I decided to use `scipy` `interp1d`.

I'm comparing heights, `hs`, and so I wrote the following:

```
f = interp1d(t_1hour, hs)
Hs10min = f(t_10min)
```

This returns te following error:

```
ValueError: object arrays are not supported
```

What does this mean? Is there any way of doing this?
BTW, I also converted the values of the 10 minute time step data frame into Timestamps so that I would be comparing the same type of data.

If you need any more information let me know!

Thank you in Advance!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [interp1d for pandas time series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58937981/interp1d-for-pandas-time-series)

Comment: Unfortunately it does not, but thank you anyways!

Comment: Well, the point raised in the suggested duplicate is that you can only feed `interp1` floats. Your `t_1hour` contains `Timestamps`, so you cannot do that.

Comment: convert strings to `pandas.Timestamps` with `pandas.to_datetime`.  Interpolation can be done with pandas by setting the timestamp as the index, resampling then interpolating, eg `df.resample("h").interpolate(method="linear")`